# Estou com problema para compilar um código java usando packages no linux

Tags: java, classes, objetos, packages

Não sei exatamente o comando para compilar um arquivo em java no linux que compartilha de uma mesma package.
Tentei seguir este tutorial:https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-compile-packages-java.cfm mas está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Classe01
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pacote1/Classe01 (wrong name:Classe01)
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
/* Classe01.java */
package pacote1;

public class Classe01{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Classe02 obj1 = new Classe02("abc");
      Classe02 obj2 = new Classe02("abc");
      System.out.println(obj1==obj2);
   }
}


/* Classe02.java */
package pacote1;

public class Classe02{
  private String valor;

  public Classe02(String s){
    valor = s;
  }
  public String getValor(){
    return valor;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Larissa, só para entendermos melhor a sua dúvida, você esta tentando compilar as classes na mão ou esta usando alguma IDE (Netbeans ou Eclipse)? Fora isso, eu imagino que a estrutura do seu projeto esteja assim, uma pasta chamada `pacote1` e dentro desta pasta você tem 2 arquivos `Classe01.java` e `Classe02.java`, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Verifique se não está faltando adicionar a extensão `.java` ao nome da classe na hora que chama o compilador `javac`. Já para rodar a aplicação na JVM (comando `java`) isso não é necessário.

Comment: @MuriloPortugal to tentando compilar as classes na mão. É isso mesmo.

Comment: @Piovezan não falou adicionar a extensão .java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Larissa, como você esta compilando na mão, tem que levar em conta algumas considerações:

1° Você escreve o código nos arquivos `.java`, mas antes de criar o    executável JAR deve compilar os arquivos `.java` em `.class`.

2° Deve-se criar um arquivo que indique ao JAVA onde está o seu    método `public static void main(String[ ] args)`, este arquivo é    conhecido como `MANIFEST`.

3° Depois de compilado e criado o `MANIFEST` você já pode empacotar tudo em um executável `.jar`.

Com estas considerações em mente, primeiro vamos compilar as suas classes .java em .class.
Para fazer isso, pelo terminal ou CMD vá até mesmo nível da sua pasta `pacote1` (não entre em pacote1, só esteja no mesmo nível que ela) e digite no terminal:

```
javac pacote1/*.java
```

Este comando irá compilar todos os arquivos com extenção `.java` que estiverem dentro da pasta `pacote1`, você verá que apareceram mais 2 arquivos, `Classe01.class` e `Class02.class`.

Agora vamos criar o `MANIFEST`, ainda no mesmo nível que sua pasta `pacote1` crie um arquivo MANIFEST.txt e dentro dele coloque o conteúdo abaixo:

```
Main-Class: pacote1.Classe01
Name: pacote1/Classe01.class
Java-Bean: True
```

Agora você só precisa executar o comando abaixo para que suas classes compiladas e o manifest sejam empacotados em um arquivo `.jar`.

```
jar cfm seuArquivo.jar manifest.txt pacote1/*.class
```

E para testar execute o comando:

```
java -jar seuArquivo.jar
```

Obs: Fazer essa compilação na mão é bem trabalhoso, visto que qualquer alteração que você fizer no código vai ter que compilar as classes e gerar o `.jar` novamente, fora que se for utilizar bibliotecas de terceiros, terá que informa-las no `MANIFEST`, eu recomendo a utilização de uma IDE pois esta já automatiza todo esse processo.

Comment: Só troque o MAINFEST por MANIFEST e está tudo certo :) +1

Comment: @Piovezan obrigado por avisar, nem tinha me tocado que escrevi errado! rsrs